# Incorrect string value error - Python + mariaDB

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, mariadb

I am using the Python mysql-connector module to insert unicode character point 128049 (U+1F431) into a mariaDB sql table.

My SQL table is defined as:

```
show create table t1;

CREATE TABLE `t1` (
`c1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

And the python code is:

```
import mysql.connector as db
conn = db.connect(sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES')
curs = conn.cursor(prepared = True)
curs.execute('insert into t1 (c1) values(%)', chr(128049))
```

Since this is a [plane 1 unicode value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) it needs 4 bytes, but changing the table and column to utf8mb4 [as suggested here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/unicode/) didn't work.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\xB1' for column 'c1' at row 1
```

The string being inserted looks correct when compared to:

```
chr(128049).encode('utf-8')
```

The sql_mode for this version of mariadb is not strict by default. While the insert works when I do not specify strict mode, the characters are converted to the default '?' character.

I can't figure out how why SQL thinks this is an invalid string.

I am connecting to mariadb 10.1.9 via mysql-connector 2.1.4 in python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection needs to specify utf8mb4.  Or `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.  This is to specify the encoding of the client's bytes.

is a 4-byte Emoji.

More Python tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Answer (score 0):

Rick James answer is correct. From that I was able to create a solution that worked for me.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
```

Sets 3 global variables as [seen here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-names/). The only issue is this only sets *session* variables so you have to issue this command for every connection.

It doesn't appear possible to set those 3 variables in the mysqld group of the my.cnf file (I believe this is because they can not be set at the command line. Note the missing command line detail in the definitions [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#character_set_client))

Instead I set the [init_file](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#init_file) option in the mysqld group of the my.cnf options file.

```
[mysqld]
init_file=/path/to/file.sql
```

Within that file I set the 3 variables:

```
set @@global.character_set_client='utf8mb4';
set @@global.character_set_connection='utf8mb4';
set @@global.character_set_results='utf8mb4';
```

Setting these globally forced the session variables to the same value. Problem solved.